# How can one pull every other value within a list?

Tags: python, list

How would one create a sublist by pulling every other element within another list.

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a = ['12','23','34']
```

I then use the enumerate function to assign a value to each element within the list.

```
b = list(enumerate(a, start=1))
```

So the result of b (key, values):

```
>>> b
>>> [(1,'12'),(2,'23'),(3, '34')]
```

Now, I've been looking around the internet (mainly using Google) and I've been reading documentation but I can't find a direct answer. How can I pull every odd key into another list?

The results that I want:

```
 [(1,'12'),(3,'34')]
```

Here's what I've been trying:

1.)

```
for i in b:
    c = b[i%2 == 1]
```

2.)

```
for i in b:
    if (i%2):
        c = i
```

If you have any suggestions for improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to get every other element:

```
>>> b = [(1, '12'), (2, '23'), (3, '34')]
>>> b[::2]
[(1, '12'), (3, '34')]
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, this is a correct answer, thank you so much. But as a side question, is there a way to extract the keys only from the enumerate object? Like, if I type, b.keys, can that print out every key value within the list?

Comment: If you mean you want `['12', '34']`, then a list comprehension will work: `[x[1] for x in b[::2]]`.

Comment: Not ['12','34'] but rather (1,2).. Is that possible?

Comment: Where is the `2` coming from?  Don't you mean `(1, 3)`?  If so, you can just do `x[0]` instead of `x[1]`: `[x[0] for x in b[::2]]`.

Comment: Good when one starts from `b`, but if one starts from the original list of strings `a` from the answer, this is not the most direct way of doing things, as even-indexed tuples are created only to be discarded later. See the answers by Hackaholic and me for a more direct approach that starts with the original list `a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do this with iterables other than lists, you can filter using `islice`

```
>>> a = ['12', '23', '34']
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> b = islice(enumerate(a, 1), None, None, 2)
>>> for c in b:
...     print c
... 
(1, '12')
(3, '34')
```

Answer (score 1):

another approach list comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = ['12', '23', '34']
>>> [(i+1, my_list[i]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)]
[(1, '12'), (3, '34')]
```

Comment: Upvoted because this bypasses the unnecessary construction of the `b` list of tuples (like in my answer). This also avoids constructing an intermediate list with every other element of `my_list`, which is nice memory-wise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good answers already, but in general you might want to avoid enumerating values that you don't need (this avoid putting them into tuples just to discard them afterwards):

```
>>> a = ['12', '23', '34']
>>> import itertools
>>> zip(itertools.count(1, 2), a[::2])  # Only odd values are fetched and enumerated
[(1, '12'), (3, '34')]
```

`count()` returns here 1, 3, 5, etc. This directly uses the original list `a` and avoids using an intermediate list of tuples `b`.

If memory were an issue, the intermediate list construction `a[::2]` can be bypassed by replacing it with `itertools.islice(a, None, None, 2)` (in a way similar to gnibbler's `b`-based answer), which uses only a fixed and small amount of memory.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
[(n, e) for n, e in enumerate(a, start=1) if n % 2 !=0]
```

Comment: The slice notation `[::2]` is here for that…